# how to filter an array of objects using drop-down list

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, dropdown

I need to filter an array of objects using couple  of drop-down lists, my problem is that if i pick All ( value = null) from the drop-downs then filter doesn't work and returns an empty array. Here is my code:

```
    let filterByName = nameValue === null ?
          function( result ) { return true; } :
          function( result ) { return result.name === nameValue };
    let filterByAge = ageValue === null ?
          function( result ) { return true; } :
          function( result ) { return result.age === ageValue };             
    let filterByCity = cityValue === null ?
          function( result ) { return true; } :
          function( result ) { return result.city=== cityValue };

    let filteredResults = formattedResult
              .filter( filterByName )
              .filter( filterByAge )
              .filter( filterByCity );
```

### HTML

```
<select>
  <option value=null>All</option>
    <% names.forEach( function( name ) { %>
  <option value="<%= name%>"><%=name%></option>
  <% }) %>
</select>
```

and so on for the other drop-downs.. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a friend suggested, just changed the value to " " and it worked! :)

```
<select>
  <option value="">All</option>
   <% names.forEach( function( name ) { %>
  <option value="<%= name%>"><%=name%></option>
   <% }) %>
</select>
```